# Convert To Edit No longer works in the moderator queue on Expanded Posts with Comments

Tags: bug, not-an-answer, moderator-tools

Convert To Edit no longer works on posts in the moderator queue that have comments, even when that post is 'expanded' in the moderator view.

I think this is broken because of the design change, but I could be wrong.

**Previous Behavior:**

The <kbd>convert to edit</kbd> button was available for answers where the user also asked the question; except when there were comments. To convert to an edit at that point, you had to 'expand the post' by clicking the 'right' arrow at the top of the post in the moderator queue:

[image: example of condensed post]

Once you did that, you used to be able to click <kbd>convert to Edit</kbd>, even if it was previously disabled:

[image: example of expanded post]

Now, you can not.

**Expected Behavior**:

Moderators should be able to convert a post to an edit, even if it has comments, when in the 'expanded' view.  (As a plus, we should still be able to do it if it's in the compact view -- just show us the comments as well -- but that's more of a feature request).

Comment: I don't think this is new since the update.  I've had to go to the mod menu for a while to do this.  I never realized it was broken.

Comment: @bluefeet It wasn't always like this; but I shamefully I haven't moderated as intensively recently as I should have been, so I don't know when it was broken.